Wave tool accessibility html5 video alert
We are addressing WCAG accessibility issues on our website and encountering a problem with the homepage slider. Our slider features four videos, each displaying text to highlight our technology.
We have received accessibility alerts related to the transcripts for these videos (details listed below).
https://wave.webaim.org/report#/https://stagematellio.dynamicwebsite.co.in/matellio-live/
wave accessibility tool audio video alert

From my understanding, this issue occurs when a video lacks a transcript. To address this, I added a dummy .vtt file to the video tag (details below), but the tool still did not recognize the fix.
<video width="100%" height="100%" preload playsinline autoplay loop muted >
                    <source src="<?php echo S3_URL; ?>/assets/images/home-new-images/Ai-4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="http://stagematellio.dynamicwebsite.co.in/matellio-live/assets/sample.vtt" default>
         
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


While captions greatly improve accessibility and usability, they are not a transcript.
Understanding SC 1.2.1: Audio-only and Video-only (Prerecorded) (Level A) mentions:

Either an alternative for time-based media or an audio track is provided that presents equivalent information for prerecorded video-only content.

The key here is that captions are still time-based, in that they all show at specific times and for limited duration only.
A transcript allows reading the same information without time limitations.
But good news:

If you already have captions, you can use that file to create the transcript. Most caption-editing tools provide an option to export a plain text transcript. Otherwise, you will need to delete the timestamps, or edit them per below.

More on Transcripts by the Web Accessibility Initative
